# How to rewrite PHP wesite url?

Tags: mod-rewrite

my website url is : `http://localhost/kubas/?page=home` or

```
http://localhost/kubas/index.php?page=home
```

I want to make `http://localhost/kubas/home` how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Your tagging this `mod-rewrite` indicates you know what's needed to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

Remeber that the browser automatically looks for the INDEX page.

It would appear that your "home" is being pulled from another source, and being dynamically inserted into the INDEX page

If you want the HOME page to load without using the $_GET function to pull your home page "content", you will need to manually insert all of the HOME PAGE content into the INDEX.php page, from there you will need to insert the index page e.g. (index.php) into your HOME..."FOLDER".

The browser will then go to HOME folder, look for INDEX.php and vioala!